# Sculpt Smooth deletes faces

Tags: sculpting, smooth, remesh

Smoothing corners deletes entire faces.

These are the steps I took:

- Imported an svg
- scaled up
- extruded on Z axis
- create a mesh, remesh with voxel 0.001 size

When I smooth it has this effect:
https://imgur.com/a/vdGJo55.gif

Any ideas why this is happening?

[image]

Comment: Please add the images and/or gifs through the available features while writing. Links to videos are accetable but it's just a tiny bit inconvinient. About your issue, I will try to look for a solution if I am able to recreate it.

Comment: Hello, please provide the blend file in your question so we can take a closer look. You can use: [Blend Exchange](https://blend-exchange.com/)

Comment: @e3_productions I just uploaded it

Comment: Thank you! I found the issue! If the solution works for you, please approve the answer so other people know it's a valid answer. I'm telling you this just in case because your account is new :)

Comment: @e3_productions this is my first post so that's very helpful! I'll try it out soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had a Remesh modifier on the model. So the Sculpting wasn't taking the new geometry into account and rather the old geometry which after taking a look at, had little geometry on the sides. Sculpt mode deletes faces when you smooth sometimes so that's why the entire face was disappearing.

> **The fix? You can just apply the modifier and smooth that mesh to your heart's content.**
>
> **You can apply by going to the modifier drop-down options and choosing "Apply".

[image]

***(shortcut: you can also just hover your mouse over the modifier and press  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>A</kbd> )***

Side Note: Instead of converting the svg to a mesh, I recommend that you go to it's geometry settings and extrude from there. If you still want to convert it to a mesh, use a solidify modifier and apply that instead of extruding. The Remesh Modifier creates A LOT of unnecessary geometry depending on the mesh you use. Especially considering the fact that you might not want to put just ONE object in your scene. After I applied the Remesh Modifier, this is the geometry count:

[image]

My viewport lagged a bit. So, Unless you have an insanely powerful GPU that handles 1 MILLION Vertices with ease (unlike mine :<), try to create low density meshes and use non-destructive workflows.

Comment: That 100% worked! I'll try using your better workflow as well.